# Jenkins pipeline - use same location and credentials as Jenkinsfile definition

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

When we define a Jenkinsfile location in the "Pipeline script from SCM" we define the Jenkinsfile location and credetials that should be used to the SCM.

But within the Jenkins file we actually put the same url and credentialsId. Seems like code dublication. Another problem, we dont want users that editing the Jenkinsfile put any credentialsId but use the one that defined in the Jenkins job step under "SCM definitions".

Is it possible to get SCM location and credentialsId from the job?

Answer (score 2):

I am getting branch and git scm location configured in the job like below

```
   def pipelineRepoBranchName = scm.branches[0]
   def pipelineRepositoryUrl = scm.userRemoteConfigs[0].url
```

If you dig deeper you can find the way to access credential id as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I found this examples:
`def scmCred = scm.getUserRemoteConfigs()[0].getCredentialsId()`
`def scmUrl = scm.getUserRemoteConfigs()[0]. getUrl()`
But the problem that we use Subversion plugin and NOT Git. I'm not sure it will work.

Comment: I never used Subversion.. I think it should work for subversion as well.

Comment: For Subversion, it seems to work with `def scmCredentialsId = scm.getLocations()[0].credentialsId`